# Zip file becomes corrupted when sending from Java to WebService

Tags: java, web-services, post, zip

I have an issue that when I submit a valid Zip file from a Java program to my Web application, the Web Application interprets the Zip file as corrupted. Issuing the file directly to the Web Application via a Web Browser allows the same Zip file to be interpreted correctly. So what am I doing wrong in my Java program?

My Java Web Application can accept Zip files through a web service via HTTP POST. I looked at the bytes received on the Web Application and they are different if I send the file through the browser to when I send via my Java program.

I know that the Zip is correct since my Web Application accepts it without error when submitted through the Web Application. I just don't know what has gone wrong when I send it via my Java program. The error that occurs on the server side is :

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 231 but got 100 bytes)

I suspect the issue has to be with either how I am creating my payload (byte array) or the request properties (or lack of correct properties) on my URL connection. The code I am using to send my zip file is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Convert the input file into a byte array 
    File inputFile = new File("C:/temp/myZip.zip");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
    }

    Object payload = new String(bos.toByteArray());
    fis.close();


    // Setup a URL connection with the appropriate properties
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/ws/rest");
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

    urlc.setDoOutput(true);
    urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    urlc.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    urlc.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/text");
    urlc.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    urlc.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    // Submit the payload to my Web Service
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
    ps.print(payload);
    ps.close();
    InputStream stream = getInputStream(urlc);
}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with that how you create your byte array, you can test it by creating a new `.zip` based on it

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/myZip2.zip");
fos.write(bos.toByteArray());
```

Try to use `.write()` with your byte array instead of using `.print()` with a string. Accordingly to the javadoc both of them come down to `.write()` but in your case you're sending byte representation of your string of byte representation of `.zip` file instead of just byte representation of `.zip`. I am not sure that it is a cause your problem but it worth a try.

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(urlc.getOutputStream());
ps.write(bos.toByteArray());
ps.close();
```

If it didn't help - let me know how your server `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/ws/rest` handles incomming file, what does it expect to receive.

Comment: Interestingly the change to the use of ps.write did work! I can't see why but will do some more investigation and detail my findings here!

Comment: @Phil Glad to hear that it helped. If you have any questions about explanation above - feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and execute this code to see what changes to some bytes can be:

> ```
> // Convert the input file into a byte array 
> byte[] theBytes = new byte[256];       //  use to test all 256  byte values
> for(int i=0; i < theBytes.length; i++)
>   theBytes[i] = (byte)i;
> ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(theBytes);
> ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
> for (int readNum; (readNum = bais.read(buf)) != -1;) {
>     bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
> }
> ```

```
Object payload = new String(bos.toByteArray());

// Submit the payload to my Web Service
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
ps.print(payload);
ps.close();
// Now test what was sent
byte[] endBytes = baos.toByteArray();
for(int i=0; i < endBytes.length; i++) {
  if(endBytes[i] != (byte)i) {
     System.out.println(i + " vs " + endBytes[i]); // show changed bytes
  }
}
```

`

How can the above code be properly formatted???